# Allowing views behind the status bar

Tags: android

I know this question was asked already but the answer does not work.  I am trying to put an image behind the status bar. I have tried to accomplish this for some time with many different solutions but I am not getting the solution. Doe's anyone know how to make the layout behind the status bar? I have yet to see a solid example. They didn't even use this in their I/O app otherwise, I wouldn't be asking this question.

Targeting api 21 and greater.

Using NoActionBar

```
<style name="LogInTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Which answer doesn't work? Which Android API level are you targeting? What exactly have you tried?

Comment: @m0skit0 I am targeting api 21 and greater.  None of them are working.  I am using no actionbar. I will add that in the question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want a transparent status bar.

Add this line to your style:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

Comment: You are correct. I was using fitssystemwindows in the view and that was my issue.